# Do regular ALTERs weaken the performance?

Tags: mysql, performance, innodb, architecture

In a project, we need to frequently `ALTER` the tables to delete or add columns. I wonder if this weakens the database performance in long term. If it has a considerable negative impact, what is the approach to keep the database healthy and efficient?

I was thinking of the following approaches:

1. OPTIMIZE the tables
2. CREATE a new database with the final architecture, and INSERT the entire data

The database is mysql(5.5) with InnoDB.

Comment: Sounds like you're talking about doing a 1 time clean-up, which wouldn't be a bad idea. Depending on your requirements, some shops will version control the schema, even index definitions.

Comment: Just for fun, why are you doing that?

Comment: @MaxVernon I know that it sounds crazy, but it is a live project in which the database structure is about to modified. Unfortunately, due to the rush, we could now extend the test period.

Comment: Be scared.  Rushing like that makes for problems.

Comment: @MaxVernon the project is in beta mode, not alpha. Changes to the database is not about core columns, but additional columns, usually making FK to other tables. The project is conducted based on end-user feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an intuitively-sensible concern that you've raised because it would seem to make sense that frequent DDL operations might leave little bits of messiness behind, but my experience has been that this concern is unfounded with InnoDB.

Prior to MySQL 5.6, the vast majority of [`ALTER TABLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/alter-table.html) operations actually rebuild the entire table with the new structure, copy all the data, then swap in the new table and delete the old one... so, I see very little potential for frequent changes to have a negative impact down the road.

You might, though, be well-advised to `OPTIMIZE TABLE` on tables where you've repeatedly inserted and deleted test data to clean up wasted disk space and rebuild the indexes, but unless your test data has been comparable in size to your production data, even this will disappear in the mix as the tables take on live data.